# Tomcat Could not load META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration on app deploy?

Tags: tomcat, reload

I have an application that I am try to deploy with ANT to Tomcat 6.0.32.  When tomcat starts the first time with the application present, no errors appear. My any deploy script simply copies a jar file to the application's WEB-INF/lib folder and tries to restart tomcat. When tomcat is reloaded or stopped/started from my ANT script, I get an XML lib related error shown below.

It doesn't seem to matter if I reload the app or start/stop the application, the error is always the same.

Any advice on how to prevent this error would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

```
    INFO:Could not load META-INF/services/org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
10:27:33,679 ERROR Dispatcher:27 - Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:902)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:143)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:110)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:168)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.createDocument(SAX2DOM.java:324)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.<init>(SAX2DOM.java:84)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(TransletOutputHandlerFactory.java:187)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerHandlerImpl.setResult(TransformerHandlerImpl.java:137)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.setup(DomHelper.java:205)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:181)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:107)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:893)
    ... 29 more
10:27:33,679 ERROR Dispatcher:27 - Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:902)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:143)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:110)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:168)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.createDocument(SAX2DOM.java:324)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.<init>(SAX2DOM.java:84)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(TransletOutputHandlerFactory.java:187)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerHandlerImpl.setResult(TransformerHandlerImpl.java:137)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.setup(DomHelper.java:205)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:181)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:107)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:893)
    ... 29 more
Aug 12, 2011 10:27:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
```